# Multi brand styling with React and SASS in component based structure

Tags: reactjs, sass, themes

I'm trying to adopt an existing multi brand / theme styling into a React app.
The project is structured according to Atomic Design and therefore all of the components should be styled component based. E.g.

Button.scss

```
.button {
    background: $brand-primary;
}
```

In my root component I then import the necessary brand styles:

App.tsx

```
if (brand === "brand1") {
    require("./styles/brand1.scss");
} else if (brand === "brand2") {
    require("./styles/brand2.scss");
}
```

styles/brand1.scss

```
$brand-primary: red;
```

In general the dynamic import with require() of the brand stylings seems to work. If I e.g. use normal css variables instead of scss variables it is working with this approach (but I can't use css variables due to IE11 incompatibility).

But the compiler is complaining about the usage of $brand-primary in Button.scss (Undefined variable) - what I totally understand. But I can't import the file containing the variable because I don't know which to import at this point (this is later decided on runtime in App.tsx).

So how can I reference the variable $brand-primary in my components, but set it later on runtime?

Comment: You might want to check that only one of those brand files is being imported, when I tried this require was importing both at compile time, require doesn't lazy load

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: We took a completely different approach and abstracted the sass to a separate repo that deployed CSS to a CDN then used the brand var to load the correct CSS file. Not very helpful in your situation I know...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use React Lazy and suspense to import your css files. https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Comment: You mean lazy loading the css files? Would this solve the compiler issue for not finding the variable?
React Lazy even complains when trying to lazy load the scss file because it expects a component.